# Element of list of tuples is truncated in python 3.9

Tags: python

I'm trying to populate a list with tuples of key and regex expressions.
Looking at the populated list looks good, but when I want to print it or write to file, then it gets truncated:

```
# coding: utf-8
import re

regs = []
regs.append(('szerzodes_felmondas',
  re.compile(r'\b(szerzödéséről|szerzödást|szerzödésemet|szerzödésést|szerzödéséhez|szerzdés|szerzdésre|szerzödéseddel|szerzödések|szerzdéssel|szerzödésedet|szerzdésen|szerzödésével|szerzödéseinken|szerzödéssel|szerzödéseket|szerzödést|szerzödéseinek|szerzödéseire|szerzödéseink|szerzödésed|szerzödésein|szerzödésébe|szerzözédeseket)\b',
  re.UNICODE)))

for i in regs:
    if i[0] == 'szerzodes_felmondas':
        print(i)

with open('regs_test.txt','w') as out:
    for i in regs:
        out.write(str(i)+'\n')
```

It is on python 3.9.
Why is it so, and how to overcome it?

Comment: What does the (truncated) output look like? What's missing?

Comment: why do you `str` cast `i` when writing to the file but not printing, that seems to the be the only major difference between the two

Comment: As explained in the duplicate, this is just a representation issue. Anyway, I'm not sure why you need to write a `compile` object to a file

Comment: @KaranShishoo File's `write` method only takes `str` as an argument. `print` converts internally...

Answer (score -4):

Maybe issue with unicode characters? Try `open('regs_test.txt', "w", encoding="utf-8")`

But still the content of file is gonna be

```
('szerzodes_felmondas', re.compile('\\b(szerzÃ¶dÃ©sÃ©rÅ‘l|szerzÃ¶dÃ¡st|szerzÃ¶dÃ©semet|szerzÃ¶dÃ©sÃ©st|szerzÃ¶dÃ©sÃ©hez|szerzdÃ©s|szerzdÃ©sre|szerzÃ¶dÃ©seddel|szerzÃ¶dÃ©sek|szerzdÃ©ssel|szerzÃ¶dÃ©sedet|szerzdÃ©sen|szerzÃ¶dÃ©sÃ©vel|szerzÃ¶dÃ©seinken|szerzÃ¶dÃ©ssel|sz))
```

and I am not sure, this is that you need